# How to map images at runtime from an Android device's Gallery to Textures in Unity app?

Tags: android, image, unity-game-engine, textures

I have an Android app built in Unity where I'm trying to iterate over and display N images stored in the user's android device. The idea is to read their images into Textures and map them onto quads in my Unity scene.

To simplify the problem I'm simply attempting to get hold of a single file that I know 100% exists on my device's photo gallery in the following directory "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/":

```
 string path = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20161019_142127.jpg";
 WWW www = new WWW("file://" + path);
 yield return www;

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))            
 {
     m_material.mainTexture = www.texture;
     Debug.Log("No Error, texture successfully set");
 }
 else
 {
     Debug.Log("Error returned = " + www.error);
 }
```

But I keep getting the following error message, suggesting that it failed to load the file:

`Error returned = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])' on a null object reference`

Would someone please be able to help me understand how to access this file correctly and consequently iterate over N image files in such a directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try using `File.ReadAllBytes` from `System.IO`:

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
byte[] fileByteData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
texture.LoadImage(fileByteData);
```

The texture will automatically resize when calling `LoadImage`.

Comment: Hey @Kardux, firstly thank you! I'm not sure why every suggestion that I've seen thus far has been to use the WWW class and not System.IO.File, seems a lot more sensible. However, I'm currently getting the following error: UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20161019_142127.jpg" is denied. Any ideas where and how to set permissions so that I my app can actually access the image?

Comment: @ArthurFox When you build your app you can check the **Write Access** parameter to _External (SD Card)_ in order to allow access. Check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html) for further informations.

Comment: Thanks @Kardux! That solved my problem! Whilst I've got your expertise in action, I wanted to ask you whether you knew how I could iterate over files in that folder without knowing any of their names? Essentially I want to be able to display N many photos in an Android device's photo gallery in my app.

Comment: @ArthurFox To achieve this you'll have to use [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(string path)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx). This `System.IO` namespace is really useful when handling files and directories : I would advise you to get familiar with it ;)

Comment: Epic, thanks - I'll give it a go and make sure to learn System.IO! I might come back for some more advice @kardux, i'll naturally post a new question though!